# gem simple_form label and box in one line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, simple-form

I am using gem  [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form).

The question is how to cause simple form to show the label and the textbox in one line.

So far I didn't find any beautiful solution to this.

A simple example, on this code

```
  = f.input :email, :autofocus => true
  = f.input :phone
  = f.input :password, hint: '(leave blank if you don\'t want to change it)'
```

The following output is generated

[image]

It is exactly what I need except for locating the labels (Email, Phone, Password) on the same line with Inputboxes, such that first comes label and them inputbox. Like on the following example.

[image]

It would be great if could share how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Could you show us some code please?
What have you tried yet?

If you use `simple_form_for(@article,...) do | f |` for example, you could simply say `f.input :title`
The output would be a label "Title" and a text input field. If you wanted to change the label text you could add the `:label` attribute, `f.input :title, label: "Different Title"`

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, the example is added.